# Settimeout for loop

Tags: javascript

I have written a script to get the top distance of the body to a div, I have 4 divs.

I'd like to set a time out and get each height every 5 seconds.

```
<div class="printOutputs" id="print1"></div>
<div class="printOutputs" id="print2"></div>
<div class="printOutputs" id="print3"></div>
<div class="printOutputs" id="print4"></div>
```

I get the ids

```
var ids = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.printOutputs')).map(function (element) {
  return element.id;
});
```

Created a for loop - can't seem to get each height every 5 seconds just returns 0s

```
for (var i=0;i<= ids.length;i++) {
    var limit = ids.length;
    var el = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
   (function(x) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(getTopPos(el));
           if(x === limit){
               console.log('It was the last one');
           }
       }, 1000 + (3000 * x));
   })(i);
}
```

Working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/nLr9o1x2/

Comment: Click the `<>` and post the code here in a [mcve]

Comment: You should [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have 2 loops that are both using the `i` variable for the iteration and the inner loop keeps overriding the outer `i` so that after the first outer iteration it ends up being `6` and the outer loop never gets to the second iteration.

Also, you escaped from the closure/scope problem by passing `i` as an argument to an [Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so that when your callback runs it will refer to the correct `i`, but that was only half way because you need to pass the `el` variable (that is referencing the actual `<div>` element) as well (otherwise, it will always refer to the last-assigned element in the loop):

```
for (var j = 0; j <= limit; j++) {
    (function(x, el) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(getTopPos(el));
        }, 1000 + (3000 * x));
    })(i, el);
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dene2rpt/)

Comment: I've made an update to the script https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/nLr9o1x2/26/

Answer (score -1):

Why so complicated?? No need to map to the ids, and then find the ids ( why not simply keep the elements in the array?), also you can join the setTimeout and the IIFE into one:

```
var ids = document.querySelectorAll('.printOutputs');
for (var i=0;i<= ids.length;i++) {
   setTimeout(function(x){//all in one...
       var el = ids[i];
       console.log(getTopPos(el));
       if(x === ids.length-1){
           console.log('It was the last one');
       }
   }, 1000 + (3000 * i),i);
}
```

Comment: ok cool, but still returns 0s, not returning the top height of each div

Comment: @user1177860 as this isnt code youve provided in the question, i cannot help you with that...

Comment: getTopPos(el) should return 8, 416, 832, 1264, returns 0s